# Return value from an auto calling JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I have a similar setup:

```
this.engine = function()
{
    // Select engine...
    return justTheRightEngine;
}

// Later somewhere in the implementation...
this.engine().doSomeWork();
```

I'd be happy to get rid of parenthesis after `engine`, so I tried to assign it to an auto calling function:

```
this.engine = (function()
{
    // Select engine...
    return justTheRightEngine;
})();

// Later somewhere in the implementation...
this.engine.doSomeWork();
```

But the auto-calling function just don't returns with any value (instead it returns the Window object actually). Is there any syntax / hack I can use here beside auto calling function?

Comment: When is `justTheRightEngine` available?  If it is not available at the time `this.engine` would be initialized, but is available later, then a function yielding `engine()` might be advisable.

Comment: @Geri I suspect you have a .net background, so you love getters. Fortunately this is possible. I added a solution, check it ;)

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado I have mainly Objective-C background, so I love clean designs, not getters in particular. Actually working on an Objective toolkit for JavaScript. I cannot step forward with this prototype stuff. Straved for correctly referenced superclass calls, class methods and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In recent browsers (FF >= 2.0, Chrome >=1, IE >= 9, Opera >= 9.5, Safari >= 3), this will work:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'engine', {get : function(){ 
    //Select engine ...
    return justTheRightEngine;
}});
```

We're adding a *getter property*.

Then you can call it like:

```
this.engine.doSomeWork();
```

exactly as you want.

More info: [JavaScript Get Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get)

Comment: the poor boys and girls stuck with XP/IE8 won't be able to enjoy it, though.

Comment: Simply using `get engine() { return justTheRightEngine; }` seems to be enough actually.

Comment: @geri Glad it helped you, Geri. The other option you mention is great (and much cleaner), I didn't post it because I assumed `this` was already defined in your code :). Cheers

Comment: Love it, I extensively using it with the Objective-JavaScript wrapper I created: https://github.com/eppz/eppz-js

Answer (score 0):

The difference for the function is that it's no longer called as a method of the object, but as a stand-alone function, so `this` will refer to the `window` object instead of your object. Use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call it like a method of the object:

```
this.engine = (function()
{
    // Select engine...
    return justTheRightEngine;
}).call(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still not returns the right value into 'engine'.

Comment: @Geri: Then you are probably running the code too early, i.e. when the values that the code needs doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of completeness, a simple

```
if (something_tells_me_this_engine_is_right())
    this.engine = justTheRightEngine;
```

would probably do the trick in most cases, and let people stuck with IE8/XP enjoy the show besides.

Unless of course you really need to make sure before each call that someone did not covertly turn your FireFox into an Opera browser since the last time you invoked the engine.

*(exits scene with manic cackle)*